# How can I implement Dynamic Routing with my choice of URL format?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing

My URL requirement is `countryname/statename/cityname`. For this I'm writing my own `RouteHandler` and adding one new route into the `routecollection` like this:

```
routes.Add(new Route("{*data}",
           new RouteValueDictionary(new
               {
                 controller = "Location",
                 action = "GetLocations"
               }),
           new MyRoutehandler()));
```

Now my question is: How do I generate this type of URL?

I tried `Html.ActionLink()` but it's asking for an action name and controller name.  However, in my URL format I don't have any action name or controller name.  How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't just use the following with the built-in route handler:

```
routes.MapRoute("LocationRoute",
                "{countryname}/{statename}/{cityname}", 
                new { controller = "Location", action = "GetLocations" });
```

That may conflict with the default "{controller}/{action}/{id}" route, but that would happen with your current system anyway (unless you make a custom *Route*, inheriting from `System.Web.Routing.RouteBase`, rather than a custom *Route Handler*).  The *Route Handler* is for handling what to do AFTER the route data has been extracted.  Since you're still using Controller and Action, you should still be able to use the `MvcRouteHandler`.  If you want to customize how the Route Data is extracted, you probably want a custom *Route*.

Btw, if you want to use a route which doesn't involve Controller and Action names, use `Html.RouteLink`.  `ActionLink` is just a wrapper which puts the controller and action into the `RouteValuesDictionary` and calls the same internal helper as `RouteLink`.

Although in this case, the route still has a Controller and Action ("Location" and "GetLocations"), so you can still use `ActionLink`.  I *think* `ActionLink` lets you specify a Route Name, so if you give your route a name you can specify that name in `ActionLink` and it will use that route to generate the URL (I may be wrong about that and if so you can still use `RouteLink` and manually add the controller and action route values)